# Is it possible to obtain an Apple Developer Id on MacOS v < 11

Tags: macos, macos-high-sierra, apple-developer

Is it possible to obtain an Apple Developer Id on MacOS version < 11 (specifically High Sierra)?

Does one have to install Xcode (installable on MacOS >= 11), or is there a way to apply in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly does the macOS version influence the account creation? You create an Apple account and enroll online (https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/), right?